# Creating user defined input to simplify Reclassify tool and negate need for remap

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, reclassify, error-000622

I would like to build a script tool using Arcpy that reclassifies a raster layer based on a single user input parameter. For example, if the user inputs the number 7, then 0 - 7 would reclassify as 1, anything > 7 would become NoData.

The reason I need this is; I am building a site selection tool which contains many processes. In the middle of the tool there is a Reclassify process. The workflow goes something like this:

Elevation > Slope > Slope + 0.5 > Int > Reclassify > Raster to Polygon - This is the final vector that becomes part of other vector analysis to perform a site selection. It is a polygon of all areas of suitable slope.

I have been playing around with various attempts but to no avail, mostly because the Reclassify tool will not take a variable as part of the input. Everything else in the tool works fine but I don't know to have a user-defined input determine the Reclassify process.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

# Script arguments
Elevation_Data = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Slope_Value = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# Local variables:
Slope_1 = "D:\egm722\Data\Scratch.gdb\\Slope_1"
Int_Slope = "D:\egm722\Data\Scratch.gdb\\Int_Slope"
Reclass = "D:\egm722\Data\Scratch.gdb\\Reclass"
RasPoly = "D:\egm722\Data\Scratch.gdb\\RasPoly"

# Process: Slope
arcpy.gp.Slope_sa(Elevation_Data, Slope_1, "DEGREE", "1", "PLANAR", "METER")

# Process: Raster Calculator
Slope_2 = Raster(Slope_1) + 0.5
Slope_2.save("D:\egm722\Data\Scratch.gdb\\Slope_2")

# Process: Int
arcpy.gp.Int_sa(Slope_2, Int_Slope)

# Process: Reclassify
arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(Int_Slope, "VALUE", "0 Slope_Value 1", Reclass, "NODATA")

# Process: Raster to Polygon
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(Reclass, RasPoly, "SIMPLIFY", "VALUE")
```

Here, I have attempted the variable Slope_Value to be the user-defined input as a script tool parameter type 'Long', but of course this does not work.

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\egm722\elev.py", line 26, in <module>
arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(Int_Slope, "VALUE", "0 Slope_Value 1", Reclass, "NODATA")
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 510, in <lambda>
return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Reclassify). Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter remap.
```

I cannot skip the reclassify process and delete values from the 'Raster to Polygon' output (using Select tool for example) because converting non-reclassified Raster layers using 'Raster to Polygon' takes far too long for it to be considered a viable tool.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue above by placing the remap within a list variable:

```
remap = RemapRange([[0,Slope_Value,1]])
Reclass = Reclassify(Int_Slope, "VALUE", remap, "NODATA")
Reclass.save(os.path.join(temp_Fgdb + "\\Reclass"))
```